# MongoDB update $inc resets value to 0 if script gets restarted

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a strange problem with MongoDB $inc. If the script gets restarted the .update() function will restart from 0 and dont use the current value of the database. The code looks like this:

```
exports.stats.update({n:name},{$inc: {t:1,s:num}}, {safe:true}, function(err){
if(err) console.log(err);
```

Is there some way to start the $inc from the current value or is there some hack to avoid this behavior?

Hope anybody has some solution for this problem.

Daniel

Comment: `$inc` doesn't ever reset values to 0; there's something else in your script causing this.

Comment: what is `num` it is possible that is being sent in as `0` which might be the cause of this behavour

Comment: thanks for the help. while running some test i saw a bug in some module which changed all my entrys.